# Is there an easy way to pass a document property as argument list to operators like $setEquals?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

The [`$setEquals`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setEquals/) aggregation pipeline operator has the following interface:

```
{ $setEquals: [ <expression1>, <expression2>, ... ] }
```

Now after a few `$group` stages I have a document like this:

```
{ myLists: [[...], [...], [...]] }
```

And would like to check if all those sub-arrays contain the same values, so pass it to `$setEquals`:

```
{ $setEquals: '$myLists' }
```

but mongo complains: `$setEquals needs at least two arguments had: 1`.

If I know the number of elements, I can just pass them explicitly:

```
{ $setEquals: [{ $arrayElemAt: ['$myLists', 0] }, { $arrayElemAt: ['$myLists', 1] }] }
```

If I don't know the number, I can use `$reduce` to do it sort-of element-wise, but this requires the empty set as an indicator for "false":

```
{
  $reduce: {
    input: '$myList',
    initialValue: { $arrayElemAt: ['$myList', 0] },
    in: {
      $cond: {
        if: { $setEquals: ['$$value', '$$this'] },
        then: '$$value',
        else: [],
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed the syntax does not allow using a "stored array" as the value for these operators, (can read more about it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ETsUH6HDGY1)).

So there is no "better" way than your workaround, but you do need to consider the "edge" cases:

1. `myLists` is empty.
2. `myLists` has 1 list in it.

like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      isUnique: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $in: [
              {
                $size: "$myList"
              },
              [
                0,
                1
              ]
            ]
          },
          true,
          {
            $ne: [
              {
                $reduce: {
                  input: "$myList",
                  initialValue: {
                    $arrayElemAt: [
                      "$myList",
                      0
                    ]
                  },
                  in: {
                    $cond: {
                      if: {
                        $setEquals: [
                          "$$value",
                          "$$this"
                        ]
                      },
                      then: "$$value",
                      else: []
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              []
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ETsUH6HDGY1)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `$setEquals` operator will accept physical input of set, we can not pass an array of sets by reference field, If you really need this you can try a custom logic,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `myLists` array
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `myLists` array and check current set is in filters,
- `$size` to get total filtered sets in the above filter operation
- `$gt` to check size return by the above operation is greater than 1 then return true otherwise false
- `$allElementsTrue` to check above return array of booleans are true then return true otherwise false

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      myLists: {
        $allElementsTrue: {
          $map: {
            input: "$myLists",
            in: {
              $gt: [
                {
                  $size: {
                    $filter: {
                      input: "$myLists",
                      as: "m",
                      cond: { $setEquals: ["$$m", "$$this"] }
                    }
                  }
                },
                1
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GNGGWonfZ2V)